# How to call a predicate with arguments from command line and output its solution?

Tags: swi-prolog

My actual application is more complicated than the following illustrative predicate but I chose it as it is because it covers various features which I would need to handle. I tried around with `initialization` and some of the `swipl` attributes but cannot really get it to work and also can't find good documentation on it.

Assuming this is stored in a file called app.pl:

```
t([X1, X2|[]], X3, Y) :- 
    Y1 is X1 + X2, 
    Y2 is 2 * X3, 
    Y = [Y1, Y2]
.
```

What I eventually want to be able to do is something like that (this is just plausible pseudo code):

```
swipl -f app.pl -c 't([1,2],3,Y)'
```

And then receive the response `Y = [3,6]` for further processing on STDOUT.

I don't really want to introduce necessarily a `main` procedure. Though, it would also be interesting to see how that would work, too. But my eventual goal is to call individual predicates from Python or Bash for testing.

In fewer words, I want to emulate a single invocation in a swipl REPL session from the Linux command line.

--

I found a Python package called [pyswip](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) which seems to be actively maintained and might be how I do it (not sure, yet). But I'd anyway still be interested in a command line solution because that might be relevant in several other circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now - this is the recommended [1] way to do it:

```
➜ swipl -g "t([1,2],3,Y), writeln(Y)" -t halt app.pl
[3,6]
```

1: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/how-to-call-a-predicate-with-arguments-from-command-line-and-output-its-solution/6919/5